# Can @NonNull annotations finally be used in java 8 on runtime?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

I am aware that there are loads of topics about `@NonNull` annotations already, however most of them are dated now Java 8 is there, meaning the API does not change anymore.

This question is further justified by the fact that [Annotations on Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html) are now part of Java 8.

So I would want the following code:

```
public BaseChecker(final @NonNull File directory, final @NonNull Consumer<File> fileConsumer) {
    this.directory = directory;
    this.fileConsumer = fileConsumer;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this kind of syntax possible, at all?
2. Does `@NonNull` finally work on runtime?

With working on runtime I mean:

- If annotated on `Object value`, then it should throw a `NullPointerException` if and only if `value == null`.
- This behaviour is similar to `Objects.requireNonNull(value)`.

Comment: And what behaviour would you expect of such an annotation at runtime?

Comment: @fge I would expect it to throw a `NullPointerException` iif the object `== null`, similar to how `T Objects.requireNonNull(T)` works.

Comment: OK, but the stack trace element needs to point somewhere executable, and a method declaration is not...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this syntax is possible. but no it doesnt "work" in the way you suggest. annotations are not supposed to "work" at all, they are decorations that can be inspected.

However it would be trivial to implement this type of behavior with AOP. check out AspectJ.